# GPG program not found on OS X

Tags: macos, amazon-s3, s3cmd

Trying to run s3cmd on my mac book air, receiving the following message.

> Success. Your access key and secret key worked fine :-)
>
> Now verifying that encryption works... ERROR: Test failed: GPG program
>   not found

Answer (score 14):

If you didn't already, try installing `s3cmd` with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install s3cmd
```

Or try installing `gpg` with `brew install gpg`.

Comment: `brew install gpg` did the job